# how to print nested array in html table using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

i have an array of all category and subcategory. i want to print them in table according to there parent id like following code. This array can have multiple child.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cid] => 1
            [cat_type] => 2
            [name] => Hardware
            [parent] => 0
            [subs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [cid] => 5
                            [cat_type] => 2
                            [name] => Printers
                            [parent] => 1
                            [subs] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cid] => 7
                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                            [name] => Inkjet printers
                                            [parent] => 5
                                            [subs] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cid] => 8
                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                            [name] => Laserjet Printers
                                            [parent] => 5
                                            [subs] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [cid] => 6
                            [cat_type] => 2
                            [name] => Monitors
                            [parent] => 1
                            [subs] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cid] => 9
                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                            [name] => LCD monitors
                                            [parent] => 6
                                            [subs] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cid] => 10
                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                            [name] => TFT monitors
                                            [parent] => 6
                                            [subs] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cid] => 2
            [cat_type] => 2
            [name] => Software
            [parent] => 0
            [subs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [cid] => 11
                            [cat_type] => 2
                            [name] => Antivirus
                            [parent] => 2
                            [subs] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cid] => 3
            [cat_type] => 2
            [name] => Movies
            [parent] => 0
            [subs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [cid] => 12
                            [cat_type] => 2
                            [name] => Action movies
                            [parent] => 3
                            [subs] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [cid] => 13
                            [cat_type] => 2
                            [name] => Comedy Movies
                            [parent] => 3
                            [subs] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [cid] => 14
                            [cat_type] => 2
                            [name] => Romantic movie
                            [parent] => 3
                            [subs] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [cid] => 15
                            [cat_type] => 2
                            [name] => Thriller Movies
                            [parent] => 3
                            [subs] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cid] => 4
            [cat_type] => 2
            [name] => Clothes
            [parent] => 0
            [subs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [cid] => 16
                            [cat_type] => 2
                            [name] => Mens
                            [parent] => 4
                            [subs] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cid] => 18
                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                            [name] => Shirts
                                            [parent] => 16
                                            [subs] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cid] => 19
                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                            [name] => T-shirts
                                            [parent] => 16
                                            [subs] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cid] => 20
                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                            [name] => Shirts
                                            [parent] => 16
                                            [subs] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cid] => 21
                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                            [name] => Jeans
                                            [parent] => 16
                                            [subs] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [4] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cid] => 22
                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                            [name] => Accessories
                                            [parent] => 16
                                            [subs] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [cid] => 28
                                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                                            [name] => Watches
                                                            [parent] => 22
                                                            [subs] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [cid] => 29
                                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                                            [name] => Tie
                                                            [parent] => 22
                                                            [subs] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [cid] => 30
                                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                                            [name] => cufflinks
                                                            [parent] => 22
                                                            [subs] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [cid] => 17
                            [cat_type] => 2
                            [name] => Womens
                            [parent] => 4
                            [subs] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cid] => 23
                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                            [name] => Tees
                                            [parent] => 17
                                            [subs] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cid] => 24
                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                            [name] => Skirts
                                            [parent] => 17
                                            [subs] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cid] => 25
                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                            [name] => Leggins
                                            [parent] => 17
                                            [subs] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cid] => 26
                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                            [name] => Jeans
                                            [parent] => 17
                                            [subs] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [4] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [cid] => 27
                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                            [name] => Accessories
                                            [parent] => 17
                                            [subs] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [cid] => 31
                                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                                            [name] => Earrings
                                                            [parent] => 27
                                                            [subs] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [cid] => 32
                                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                                            [name] => Bracelets
                                                            [parent] => 27
                                                            [subs] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [cid] => 33
                                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                                            [name] => Necklaces
                                                            [parent] => 27
                                                            [subs] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [3] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [cid] => 34
                                                            [cat_type] => 2
                                                            [name] => Pendants
                                                            [parent] => 27
                                                            [subs] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

```html
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Hardware</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- Printers</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- -Inkjet printers</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - Laserjet Printers</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- Monitors</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - LCD monitors</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - TFT monitors</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Software</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- Antivirus</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>Movies</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- Action movies</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- Comedy Movies</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- Romantic movie</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- Thriller Movies</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>Clothes</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- Mens</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - Shirts</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - T-shirts</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - Shirts</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - Jeans</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - Accessories</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - - Watches</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - - Tie</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - - cufflinks</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- Womens</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - Tees</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - Skirts</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - Leggins</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - Jeans</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - Accessories</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - - Earrings</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - - Bracelets</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - - Necklaces</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>- - - Pendants</td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" value="" /></label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to print a table inside a table cell?

Comment: Thanks for reply @SalimIbrogimov
No i want to print entire table with multiple row.... i mean one row will have one record...